How does set containment work in modern Sagemath?
Recently, I've been trawling through source code (the documentation wasn't too helpful) and figuring out the basic design principles for implementing new structures. I came across an official tutorial on this. I've followed it ok, but I question the content here about equality and containment. It claims the following:

If P is an instance of a custom class and x==P(x) evaluates as True without raising any errors, then x in P returns True.

I don't think this is correct, at least, not anymore. But I'm not sure what is correct. Consider the following:
V = MyCustomClassInheritingFromCombinatorialFreeModule(initialisation_data)

# V._element_class: MyCustomClassInheritingFrom(IndexedFreeModuleElement)
# V.category(): Graded algebras with basis over the rational field

two = V(ZZ(2))
t = QQ(2)

print(2 in V, 2 in QQ)
print(QQ(2) == V(QQ(2)), QQ(2) == V(2), QQ(2) in V, V(2) in V)
print(t == V(t), t == V(2), two == V(2))
print(two in V, t in V, t == two)

Outputs:
False True
True True False True
True True True
True False True

Here, V is an instance of a custom class I've been implementing, inheriting from CombinatorialFreeModule. It is defined over the rationals. I've established element constructor methods for it, and a custom element class; I've checked that it admits coercion from the rationals and the integers.
Notice that t==V(t) returns True without any error, yet t in V returns False. What? It's probably not such a big deal that something like "2" isn't automatically seen as an element of my algebra, but I would like to know what the updated correct statement is, given that this tutorial (the only thing I could find on the matter, I'm not sure what to search for) isn't right.
What's going on? If the tutorial's remark is still correct, then I guess I'll have to edit with more details, but I'd appreciate advice on what kind of thing might be going wrong. Like I said, V.has_coerce_map_from(QQ) and so on, all return True. My IDE is Visual Studio Code, working with Jupyter notebook and hooked up to a remote WSL system which has Sage installed. It's interesting to note my IDE colourises in as yellow here when I apply it to V, but when I test print(1 in QQ), in is now coloured purple (and it returns True, as expected).
I tested the tutorial's source code on my system, and noted the membership protocol works perfectly there. Also, in colourises correctly as purple for their class. Strange.
